# Visual Studio (Resetting C++ project)

Tags: c++, loadlibrary

I've never used C++ in Visual Studio but do some work with C# and VB.

I have a simple x86 C++ project that loads a 32bit DLL then uses a function from it.

It was working fine, then I changed some settings (SDK version, toolset, C++ language standard) and now I get "The specified module could not be found." when I try and load the DLL.

I've reset C++ in the "Import and export settings wizard" and then reinstalled all of Visual Studio but I can't seem to find a way to get the project back to working with this DLL.  Dumpbin shows me that all the dependencies it needs are in SYSWOW64 :/

I've made copies of the DLL and put them everywhere I can think of, but I get the same problem.  It loads with C# but I have some memory access issues passing strings to one of the functions.

Anyone had an issue like this before?

```
//Get current exe path and add DLL filename.
char cDLLPath[MAX_PATH + 1];
TCHAR bufCurrentDirectory[MAX_PATH + 1] = { 0 };
DWORD dwNumCharacters = ::GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, bufCurrentDirectory);

if (dwNumCharacters == 0)
{
    printf("Error getting executable path\n");
    exit(0);
}
snprintf(cDLLPath, MAX_PATH + 1, "%s\\MyDLL.dll", bufCurrentDirectory);
HINSTANCE myDll = LoadLibrary((LPCWSTR)cDLLPath);
//MyDLL is always NULL, error message is always "The specified module could not be found."
```

I've removed the path, tried current working folder, moved it to c:\windows\system32 etc

This function tells me the DLL path\filename are correct.

```
BOOL file_exists(const fs::path& file_path, fs::file_status s = fs::file_status{})
{
if (fs::status_known(s) ? fs::exists(s) : fs::exists(file_path)) return true;
else return false;
}
```

-Pook

Comment: `LoadLibrary((LPCWSTR)cDLLPath);` This is wrong and couldn't have worked before. You must have changed some other code and/or the Unicode setting for the project.

Comment: Yes! thank you, I changed character set to Multi-Byte and LPCWSTR to LPCSTR and all is good

Comment: It's good news that it works, but for consistency you shouldn't mix `char` and `TCHAR` in the same breath, and in today's Windows you should be compiling for Unicode since for example the Multi-Byte `GetCurrentDirectory` will return the wrong path if the current directory contains international characters outside the active codepage.

Comment: So much internet code still uses TCHAR, which is a technology that made a little bit of sense in the 1990's. Ignore it all. Use wide characters in modern code.